# Swift: How to populate table view controller with Facebook data?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to make an app that shows events from Facebook in a table view controller.

For example, I have a resturant and a Facebook page with details of my restaurant and I post that after two hours at my restaurant came Michael Jackson impersonator, I want to appear in my app in a table view controller this event.

I suppose that I need to make a reference to my page and I want to refresh this page every one hour.

How can I do that? I put a table view in my view controller, and a Facebook login button before that, and after successful login, go to this new VC with table view.